# Click a button with tasks involved such as highlight and scroll

Tags: javascript, button, task

How do you make a button do a certain task instead of just a click? I am trying to put a highlight on text and scroll on a button when you click on it. The for loop and if statement inside the function is correct? Also, I saw in a post to put extra parenthesis around beginning and end of the function. Is that correct? Please help fix this code. Thank you!

```
var press = document.createElement('press');

press.onclick = (function () {
    for (var q = 0; q < i; q++) {
        if ( x == y ) {
            document.getElementById(x).scrollIntoView(true);
            $('body').text().highlight(x);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: please indent..

Comment: `press = = document` for a start this is just wrong `= =`

Comment: you're assigning the result of that function to the `onclick` property by using an IIFE (i.e., `(function () { ... })();`...

Answer (score 0):

I have difficulty understanding your question but I will attempt answering it based on your code.

*'How do you make a button do a certain task instead of just a click?'*
You add an event listener to the button, disable the default behavior and write the task in the listeners callback.

```
btnElement.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  //Code for your task
});
```

*The for loop and if statement inside the for loop is correct?*
I am not sure if its a question or statement. Syntactically it looks correct, but I cannot say more without proper context. What is x? Please provide a working sample or more code.

*Also, I saw in a post to put extra parenthesis around beginning and end of the function. Is that correct?*
You do that only when you want to have an IFFE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). Basically, you call the anonymous function right after defining it.

*Please help fix this code. Thank you!*
Please go over the points mentioned above and make changes to your code. In order to help you fix the code I need more information about what you are trying to do. The best I can do is add indentation.

```
var press = document.createElement('button'); //Create a button element.

press.onclick = (function () {
  for ( var q = 0; q < x.length; q++) {
    if ( x == y ) {
     document.getElementById(x).scrollIntoView(true);
     $('body').text().highlight(x);
    }
  }
})();
```